# How to add a Text Overlay Wordpress Slider Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

I am using a thumbnail slider with a light box effect in a WordPress theme, that was developed by the theme.

It works great, but I'd love to be able to add a text overlay to the enlarged lightbox image. Is this even possible?

```
<?php
function theme_small_slider_shortcode($atts)
{
    global $themename;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "id" => "small_slider",
        "title" => "",
        "subtitle" => "",
        "images" => "",
        "lightbox_icon_color" => "blue_light",
        "features_images_loop" => 1,
        "autoplay" => 0,
        "pause_on_hover" => 1,
        "scroll" => 1,
        "effect" => "scroll",
        "easing" => "easeInOutQuint",
        "duration" => 750,
        "ontouch" => 0,
        "onmouse" => 0,
        "top_margin" => "page_margin_top_section"
    ), $atts));
    if($effect=="_fade")
        $effect = "fade";
    if(strpos($easing, 'ease')!==false)
    {
        $newEasing = 'ease';
        if(strpos($easing, 'inout')!==false)
            $newEasing .= 'InOut';
        else if(strpos($easing, 'in')!==false)
            $newEasing .= 'In';
        else if(strpos($easing, 'out')!==false)
            $newEasing .= 'Out';
        $newEasing .= ucfirst(substr($easing, strlen($newEasing), strlen($easing)-strlen($newEasing)));
    }
    else
        $newEasing = $easing;

    $output = '<div class="gallery_box small_slider"><ul class="image_carousel ' . $id . ' id-' . $id . ' autoplay-' . $autoplay . ' pause_on_hover-' . $pause_on_hover . ' scroll-' . $scroll . ' effect-' . $effect . ' easing-' . $newEasing . ' duration-' . $duration . ((int)$ontouch ? ' ontouch' : '') . ((int)$onmouse ? ' onmouse' : '') . ($top_margin!="none" ? ' ' . $top_margin : '') . '">';
    $images = explode(',', $images);
    $i=0;
    foreach($images as $attach_id)
    {
        $attachment = get_posts(array('p' => $attach_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));
        $output .= '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_image($attach_id, $themename . "-gallery-image", false, array("alt" => ""/*, "class" => "mc_preload"*/));
        $output .= '<ul class="controls">
                <li>
                    <a' . (isset($atts["external_url" . $i]) && $atts["external_url" . $i]!="" ? ' target="_blank"' : '') . ' href="' . (!isset($atts["external_url" . $i]) || $atts["external_url" . $i]=="" ? (isset($atts["iframe_url" . $i]) && $atts["iframe_url" . $i]!="" ? $atts["iframe_url" . $i] : (isset($atts["video_url" . $i]) && $atts["video_url" . $i]!="" ? $atts["video_url" . $i] : $attachment[0]->guid)) : $atts["external_url" . $i]) . '" class="fancybox' . (isset($atts["video_url" . $i]) && $atts["video_url" . $i]!="" ? '-video' : (isset($atts["iframe_url" . $i]) && $atts["iframe_url" . $i]!="" ? '-iframe' : (isset($atts["external_url" . $i]) && $atts["external_url" . $i]!="" ? '-url' : ''))) . ' open' . (isset($atts["video_url" . $i]) && $atts["video_url" . $i]!="" ? '_video' : (isset($atts["iframe_url" . $i]) && $atts["iframe_url" . $i]!="" ? '_iframe' : (isset($atts["external_url" . $i]) && $atts["external_url" . $i]!="" ? '_url' : ''))) . '_lightbox"' . ((!isset($atts["external_url" . $i]) || $atts["external_url" . $i]=="") && (!isset($atts["iframe_url" . $i]) || $atts["iframe_url" . $i]=="") && (!isset($atts["video_url" . $i]) || $atts["video_url" . $i]=="") ? ($features_images_loop==1 ? ' rel="small_slider' . $id . '"' : '') : '') . (isset($atts["image_title" . $i]) && $atts["image_title" . $i]!="" ? ' title="' . esc_attr($atts["image_title" . $i]) . '"' : '') . ' style="background-image: url(\'' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/icons_media/' . $lightbox_icon_color . '/' . (isset($atts["video_url" . $i]) && $atts["video_url" . $i]!="" ? 'video' : ((isset($atts["iframe_url" . $i]) && $atts["iframe_url" . $i]!="") || (isset($atts["external_url" . $i]) && $atts["external_url" . $i]!="") ? 'url' : 'image')) . '.png\')"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>';
        $i++;
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    if($title!="" || $subtitle!="")
    {
        $output .= '<div class="description">';
        if($title!="")
            $output .= '<h3>' . $title . '</h3>';
        if($subtitle!="")
            $output .= '<h5>' . $subtitle . '</h5>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("mc_small_slider", "theme_small_slider_shortcode");
//visual composer
class WPBakeryShortCode_MC_Small_Slider extends WPBakeryShortCode {
    public function content( $atts, $content = null ) {
        return theme_small_slider_shortcode($atts);
    }
   public function singleParamHtmlHolder($param, $value) {
       global $themename;
        $output = '';
        // Compatibility fixes
        $old_names = array('yellow_message', 'blue_message', 'green_message', 'button_green', 'button_grey', 'button_yellow', 'button_blue', 'button_red', 'button_orange');
        $new_names = array('alert-block', 'alert-info', 'alert-success', 'btn-success', 'btn', 'btn-info', 'btn-primary', 'btn-danger', 'btn-warning');
        $value = str_ireplace($old_names, $new_names, $value);
        //$value = __($value, "js_composer");
        //
        $param_name = isset($param['param_name']) ? $param['param_name'] : '';
        $type = isset($param['type']) ? $param['type'] : '';
        $class = isset($param['class']) ? $param['class'] : '';

        if ( isset($param['holder']) == false || $param['holder'] == 'hidden' ) {
            $output .= '<input type="hidden" class="wpb_vc_param_value ' . $param_name . ' ' . $type . ' ' . $class . '" name="' . $param_name . '" value="'.$value.'" />';
        }
        else {
            $output .= '<'.$param['holder'].' class="wpb_vc_param_value ' . $param_name . ' ' . $type . ' ' . $class . '" name="' . $param_name . '">'.$value.'</'.$param['holder'].'>';
        }
        if($param_name == 'images') {
            $images_ids = empty($value) ? array() : explode(',', trim($value));
            $output .= '<ul class="attachment-thumbnails'.( empty($images_ids) ? ' image-exists' : '' ).'">';
            foreach($images_ids as $image) {
                $img = wpb_getImageBySize(array( 'attach_id' => (int)$image, 'thumb_size' => $themename . '-small-thumb' ));
                $output .= ( $img ? '<li>'.$img['thumbnail'].'</li>' : '<li><img width="150" height="150" test="'.$image.'" src="' . WPBakeryVisualComposer::getInstance()->assetURL('vc/blank.gif') . '" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="" title="" /></li>');
            }
            $output .= '</ul>';
            $output .= '<a href="#" class="column_edit_trigger' . ( !empty($images_ids) ? ' image-exists' : '' ) . '">' . __( 'Add images', 'js_composer' ) . '</a>';

        }
        return $output;
    }
}
$params = array(
    array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Id", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "id",
        "value" => "small_slider",
        "description" => __("Please provide unique id for each carousel on the same page/post", 'medicenter')
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Title", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "title",
        "value" => ""
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Subtitle", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "subtitle",
        "value" => ""
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "attach_images",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Images", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "images",
        "value" => ""
    )
);
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++)
{
    $params[] = array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "heading" => __("Video url", 'medicenter') . " " . ($i+1),
        "param_name" => "video_url" . $i,
        "value" => "",
        "dependency" => Array('element' => "images", 'not_empty' => true),
        "description" => __('For Vimeo please use http://player.vimeo.com/video/%video_id% For YouTube: http://youtube.com/embed/%video_id%', 'medicenter')
    );
    $params[] = array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Iframe url", 'medicenter') . " " . ($i+1),
        "param_name" => "iframe_url" . $i,
        "value" => "",
        "dependency" => Array('element' => "images", 'not_empty' => true)
    );
    $params[] = array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("External url", 'medicenter') . " " . ($i+1),
        "param_name" => "external_url" . $i,
        "value" => "",
        "dependency" => Array('element' => "images", 'not_empty' => true)
    );
    $params[] = array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Image title", 'medicenter') . " " . ($i+1),
        "param_name" => "image_title" . $i,
        "value" => "",
        "dependency" => Array('element' => "images", 'not_empty' => true)
    );
}
$params = array_merge($params, array(
    array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Lightbox icon color", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "lightbox_icon_color",
        "value" => array(
            __("light blue", 'medicenter') => 'blue_light', 
            __("dark blue", 'medicenter') => 'blue_dark',
            __("blue", 'medicenter') => 'blue',
            __("black", 'medicenter') => 'black',
            __("gray", 'medicenter') => 'gray',
            __("dark gray", 'medicenter') => 'gray_dark',
            __("light gray", 'medicenter') => 'gray_light',
            __("green", 'medicenter') => 'green',
            __("dark green", 'medicenter') => 'green_dark',
            __("light green", 'medicenter') => 'green_light',
            __("orange", 'medicenter') => 'orange',
            __("dark orange", 'medicenter') => 'orange_dark',
            __("light orange", 'medicenter') => 'orange_light',
            __("red", 'medicenter') => 'red',
            __("dark red", 'medicenter') => 'red_dark',
            __("light red", 'medicenter') => 'red_light',
            __("turquoise", 'medicenter') => 'turquoise',
            __("dark turquoise", 'medicenter') => 'turquoise_dark',
            __("light turquoise", 'medicenter') => 'turquoise_light',
            __("violet", 'medicenter') => 'violet',
            __("dark violet", 'medicenter') => 'violet_dark',
            __("light violet", 'medicenter') => 'violet_light',
            __("white", 'medicenter') => 'white',
            __("yellow", 'medicenter') => 'yellow'
        )
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Lightbox images loop", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "features_images_loop",
        "value" => array(__("Yes", 'medicenter') => 1, __("No", 'medicenter') => 0),
        "dependency" => Array('element' => "images", 'not_empty' => true)
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Autoplay", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "autoplay",
        "value" => array(__("No", 'medicenter') => 0, __("Yes", 'medicenter') => 1)
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Pause on hover", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "pause_on_hover",
        "value" => array(__("Yes", 'medicenter') => 1, __("No", 'medicenter') => 0),
        "dependency" => Array('element' => "autoplay", 'value' => 1)
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Scroll", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "scroll",
        "value" => 1,
        "description" => __("Number of items to scroll in one step", 'medicenter')
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Effect", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "effect",
        "value" => array(
            __("scroll", 'medicenter') => "scroll", 
            __("none", 'medicenter') => "none", 
            __("directscroll", 'medicenter') => "directscroll",
            __("fade", 'medicenter') => "_fade",
            __("crossfade", 'medicenter') => "crossfade",
            __("cover", 'medicenter') => "cover",
            __("uncover", 'medicenter') => "uncover"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Sliding easing", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "easing",
        "value" => array(
            __("easeInOutQuint", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutQuint",
            __("swing", 'medicenter') => "swing", 
            __("linear", 'medicenter') => "linear", 
            __("easeInQuad", 'medicenter') => "easeInQuad",
            __("easeOutQuad", 'medicenter') => "easeOutQuad",
            __("easeInOutQuad", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutQuad",
            __("easeInCubic", 'medicenter') => "easeInCubic",
            __("easeOutCubic", 'medicenter') => "easeOutCubic",
            __("easeInOutCubic", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutCubic",
            __("easeInQuart", 'medicenter') => "easeInQuart",
            __("easeOutQuart", 'medicenter') => "easeOutQuart",
            __("easeInOutQuart", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutQuart",
            __("easeInSine", 'medicenter') => "easeInSine",
            __("easeOutSine", 'medicenter') => "easeOutSine",
            __("easeInOutSine", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutSine",
            __("easeInExpo", 'medicenter') => "easeInExpo",
            __("easeOutExpo", 'medicenter') => "easeOutExpo",
            __("easeInOutExpo", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutExpo",
            __("easeInQuint", 'medicenter') => "easeInQuint",
            __("easeOutQuint", 'medicenter') => "easeOutQuint",
            __("easeInCirc", 'medicenter') => "easeInCirc",
            __("easeOutCirc", 'medicenter') => "easeOutCirc",
            __("easeInOutCirc", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutCirc",
            __("easeInElastic", 'medicenter') => "easeInElastic",
            __("easeOutElastic", 'medicenter') => "easeOutElastic",
            __("easeInOutElastic", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutElastic",
            __("easeInBack", 'medicenter') => "easeInBack",
            __("easeOutBack", 'medicenter') => "easeOutBack",
            __("easeInOutBack", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutBack",
            __("easeInBounce", 'medicenter') => "easeInBounce",
            __("easeOutBounce", 'medicenter') => "easeOutBounce",
            __("easeInOutBounce", 'medicenter') => "easeInOutBounce"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "textfield",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Sliding transition speed (ms)", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "duration",
        "value" => 750
    ),
    /*array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Slide on touch", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "ontouch",
        "value" => array(__("No", 'medicenter') => 0, __("Yes", 'medicenter') => 1)
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Slide on mouse", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "onmouse",
        "value" => array(__("No", 'medicenter') => 0, __("Yes", 'medicenter') => 1)
    ),*/
    array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __("Top margin", 'medicenter'),
        "param_name" => "top_margin",
        "value" => array(__("Section (large)", 'medicenter') => "page_margin_top_section", __("Page (small)", 'medicenter') => "page_margin_top", __("None", 'medicenter') => "none")
    )
));
wpb_map( array(
    "name" => __("Small slider", 'medicenter'),
    "base" => "mc_small_slider",
    "class" => "",
    "controls" => "full",
    "show_settings_on_create" => true,
    "icon" => "icon-wpb-layer-small-slider",
    "category" => __('MediCenter', 'medicenter'),
    "params" => $params
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that you don't need to know any PHP to do this. It can be done with Jquery which is part of WordPress. Use this plugin if your just getting started with WP so that you can write JS or Jquery on the page without much hassle.

[**WP JavaScript Adder**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/html-javascript-adder/)